# Switching between two forms

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In MFC, I have two forms. Using a button, I want to switch control from one form to another form.

Comment: Are both forms visible at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 related forms, the best way is to use CPropertySheet and CPropertyPage then you can switch between them using the tabs.